# How to save iPhone Messages photos and videos and create free space?

Tags: iphone, icloud, high-sierra, messages

We have an iPhone that has run out of space. Most of the space is taken by Messages. We don't want to delete all those old photos and videos. We'd like to save them to our Photos app.

The latest version of iOS and macOS possibly syncs all your Messages between your connect iCloud devices. If true, ***all*** of our photos and videos from Messages on the iPhone should be on the Mac connected with the same iCloud account.

I also understand there is a folder on the Mac under `~/Library/Messages/Attachments` which contains ***all*** the photos and videos from the macOS Messages app, which based on my assuming that all messages are synced between iCloud and all connected devices, should represent ***all*** of the photos and videos from the Messages app on the iPhone.

My questions are:

1. Should the Mac Messages app contain ***all*** of the iPhone Messages, including ***all*** of the photos and videos in those messages?
2. Shouldn't I be able to import that `/Attachments` folder into Photos app on the Mac to backup/save ***all*** of the photos and videos from the Messages app on the iPhone?
3. If and once I do back then up, is it safe to assume that if we delete those photos and videos from the iPhone to free space, that those same photos and videos will also be delete from the Mac Messages app (but obviously, not the Photos app if imported before)?

Thank you.

Comment: my folder ~/Library/Messages/Attachments folder appears to only contain 2018 messages.